# Read multiple files and store filename as key and value as the contents of the file in python dictonary

Tags: python, file-handling

I currently have a list with the following filenames
[file1, file2]
I want to read each files by iterating through the list and read the contents of the file into dictionary

So I am trying to create dictionary with key and value as :

thisisdict={ "file1" : "abcdefgh",
"file2" :" defssfifj"}

I am able to read and store values of each individuals files but unsure when multiple filenames are to iterated and opened and read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
thisisdict = { f: open(f).read() for f in ["file1", "file2"]}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should be fairly easy, if I understand your requirement right.

```
my_dict = {}
for filename in ['file1.txt', 'file2.txt']:
    with open(filename, 'r') as f:
        _t = f.read()
        my_dict.update({filename: _t})
```

Of course, this is a simple solution for small files, this can be done better if you have massive files etc.